# How to populate a table with an id attribute that is predefined as a foreign key in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, nested, sql-insert

I have three tables in my database:

1. HASSKILLS with attributes (**skillid**, attribute 1, attribute 2, attribute 3) - **skillid** is the primary key and a foreign key to SKILLS
2. OLDHASSKILLS with attribute (**description**, attribute 1, attribute 2, attribute 3) - **description** is the primary key
3. SKILLS with attributes (**skillid, description**) - **skillid** is the primary key

Each **skillid** in SKILLS is unique to a single description (e.g. '3', 'can climb trees')

I have created the HASSKILLS table, which will eventually replace my OLDHASSKILLS, as I want to refer and use the **skillid** to reference SKILLS, rather than the description.

OLDHASSKILLS and SKILLS are all populated with data and my HASSKILLS is also populated, except for the **skillid**.

I want to effectively replace all the **description** values with the corresponding **skillid** values in the new HASSKILLS table.

I have tried doing this by using an INSERT INTO statement and a nested query.

```
INSERT INTO HASSKILLS(SkillId) 
    SELECT SkillId 
    FROM SKILLS 
    WHERE 
        (SELECT d1.description, d2.description 
         FROM OLDHASSKILLS d1, SKILLS d2 
         WHERE d1.description = d2.description);
```

I am getting something wrong with 'WHERE (SELECT' and an error subquery must only return one column.

Have I made an error in my SQL statement, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: That makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join in the `FROM` clause, not in a totally unconnected subquery.

```
INSERT INTO hasskills
            (skillid,
             attribute1,
             attribute2,
             attribute3) 
            SELECT s.skillid,
                   ohs.attribute1,
                   ohs.attribute2,
                   ohs.attribute3
                   FROM oldhasskills ohs
                        INNER JOIN skills s
                                   ON ohs.description = s.description;
```